# Do high CP Pokemon spawn more often after a long day of playing Pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I found High CP Pokemons more often after walking long distances and capturing Pokemon gyms. Do you think the game spawns more High CP Pokemon depending on the amount of XP gained recently? It might also depend on the amount of distance traveled. Is this a known behavior?

Answer (score 7):

I have searched a lot for this and I can tell you, with confidence, that it does not happen.

You either got lucky or high CP Pokemon you encountered were simply more memorable compared to the low CP ones.